# Unable to run applet program in web browser but works fine in applet viewer?

Tags: java, html, browser, applet

applet program is just working fine applet viewer but when trying to run in browser it shows runtime exception *java.lang.reflect.InvocationException* and a window shows the following details

```
    Java Plug-in 10.7.2.11
    Using JRE version 1.7.0_07-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
    User home directory = C:\Users\tom
    ----------------------------------------------------
    c:   clear console window
    f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
    g:   garbage collect
    h:   display this help message
    l:   dump classloader list
    m:   print memory usage
    o:   trigger logging
    q:   hide console
    r:   reload policy configuration
    s:   dump system and deployment properties
    t:   dump thread list
    v:   dump thread stack
    x:   clear classloader cache
    0-5: set trace level to <n>
    -----------------------------------------
    -----------
```

here is my html code for running applet

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <applet code="integrity.class" width="800" height="500">
    </applet>
    </body>
    </html>
```

help me fix this!!

Comment: Let's start with the fact that the `applet` tag is deprecated and move on from there.  It would "seem" like you're missing the code base attribute, which is going to make it hard for the browser to know where to load your class from. Have a read through [The APPLET Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html) and [Deploying an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the code on your package path to your applet class, and the archive to the path of the jar, like this:

```
<applet code="my.applet.package.Integrity" archive="integrity.jar" width="800" height="500">
```

Also note that class names should start with uppercase in Java